# Is there anyway to block/whitelist certain ASN number on Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, firewall

I knew how to configure ufw or (iptables), but how do I whitelist certain ASN number on Ubuntu?

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:    focal
```